# Python 3 gives error Unresolved reference 'long'

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I have a problem where my structure from Python 2.7 gives me errors in Python 3.5.

Here is the code

```
python_types = {
    TYPE_DOUBLE: float,
    TYPE_FLOAT: float,
    TYPE_INT64: long,
    TYPE_UINT64: long,
    TYPE_INT32: int,
    TYPE_FIXED64: float,
    TYPE_FIXED32: float,
    TYPE_BOOL: bool,
    TYPE_STRING: unicode,
}
```

I only get errors for long and unicode types but other types are ok. Can someone please explain to me why that is?

Comment: python 3 moved to using ints for all integers, with infinite precision. there is no `long` datatype anymore.

Comment: Yes. Python 3 no longer has `long` (rather that is just `int`) nor `unicode` (that is now just `str`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal) included in Python 3.0, `long` was merged with `int` and only `int` exists now.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/

You can also see reference to it in the 'What's new' release note from Python 3.0 here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers